# how to add row line for the tableview in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display a table details in the `tableView` in the form of rows and columns as show below.

[image: table image]

I have implemented a `UITableView` in a `ViewController`, and added a Custom cell and displayed the data as shown

[image: i have implemented]

Now i dont want space between the cell .Instead i need a vertical line between the cell  as in the image.

Here is my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     AttendenceTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
     AttendenceTableViewCell*cell=[[AttendenceTableViewCell alloc]init];
     if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[ AttendenceTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
     }
     cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.24 green:0.67 blue:0.94 alpha:1.0];
     _attendenceTableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

     cell.dateLabel.text=@"Date";
     cell.timeInLabel.text=@"in";
     cell.timeOutLabel.text=@"out";;
     cell.DurationLabel.text=@"duration";
     cell.statusLabel.text=@"status";
     [spinner stopAnimating];
     return cell;
}
```

how can i achieve it...?

Comment: are can use view in storyboard to show line .

Comment: i want to shoe lines between date ,in ,out,duration,status.

Comment: i tried a view in between them but it look  clumsy.

Comment: Is there any another way...?

Comment: so you can take a view set its height equal to your row height and set its width = 1.

Comment: it's the best and easy way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please take a prototype cell or custom cell like this it will be help you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of the table cell by delegate method to remove space

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 45.0;
}
```

For line between data :
1. Add view for different label.
2. Add the label to the view.
3. Change the background color of the view.

Answer (score 0):

add UIImageView on AttendenceTableViewCell *cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Each cell will have a vertical line

Answer (score 0):

In AttendanceTableViewCell, you can add a view (programatically) like this(on your init method or in awakeFromNib):

```
CGFloat lineWidht = 2.00; // <- set the line width
UIColor *bgColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200/255.0 green:199/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1.0];

CGRect horizontalLineFrame = CGRectMake(self.contentView.frame.size.width - lineWidht, 0, lineWidht, self.contentView.frame.size.height);

UIView *horizontalLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:horizontalLineFrame];
horizontalLine.backgroundColor = bgColor;
[self.contentView addSubview:horizontalLine];
```